# d3 Update stacked bar graph using selection.join

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a stacked bar graph which should update on changing data and I want to use d3v5 and selection.join as explained here https://observablehq.com/@d3/learn-d3-joins?collection=@d3/learn-d3.
When entering the data everything works as expected, however the update function is never called (that's the console.log() for debugging.).
So it looks like it is just entering new data all the time.
How can I get this to work as expected?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .y.axis .domain {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    let xVar = "year";

    let alphabet = "abcdef".split("");
    let years = [1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003];

    let margin = { left:80, right:20, top:50, bottom:100 };

    let width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    let g = d3.select("#chart")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

    let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#66c2a5","#fc8d62","#8da0cb","#e78ac3","#a6d854","#ffd92f"])
    let x = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .domain(years)
        .padding(.25);

    let y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    let yAxis = d3.axisRight(y)
      .tickSize(width)

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    let stack = d3.stack()
        .keys(alphabet)
        .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
        .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

    redraw(randomData());

    d3.interval(function(){
      redraw(randomData());  
    }, 1000);

    function redraw(data){

      // update the y scale
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(d => d.sum ))])
      g.select(".y")
        .transition().duration(1000)
          .call(yAxis);

      groups = g.append('g')
        .selectAll('g')
        .data(stack(data))
        .join('g')
        .style('fill', (d,i) => color(d.key));
      groups.selectAll('.stack')
        .data(d => d)
        .attr('class', 'stack')
        .join(
          enter => enter.append('rect')
            .data(d => d)
              .attr('x', d => x(d.data.year))
              .attr('y', y(0))
              .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
            .call(enter => enter.transition().duration(1000)
              .attr('y', d => y(d[1]))
              .attr('height', d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
            ),
          update => update
          .attr('x', d => x(d.data.year))
          .attr('y', y(0))
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
            .call(update => update.transition().duration(1000)
            .attr('y', d => y(d[1]))
              .attr('height', d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
            .attr(d => console.log('update stack'))
          )
      )

    }

    function randomData(data){
      return years.map(function(d){
        let obj = {};
        obj.year = d;
        let nums = [];
        alphabet.forEach(function(e){
          let num = Math.round(Math.random()*2);
          obj[e] = num;
          nums.push(num);
        });
        obj.sum = nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        return obj;
      });
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is it in a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/blabbath/yeq5d1tp/

EDIT: I provided a wrong link first, here is the right one.
My example is heavily based on this: https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/7e3ec1a6722a153a5d102b6c42f4501d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue a few days ago. The way I did it is as follows:

We have two `.join`, the parent one is for the stack and the child is for the rectangles.

In the `enter` of the parent join, we call the `updateRects` in order to draw the rectangles for the first time, this `updateRects` function will do the child `.join`, this second join function will draw the rectangles.

For the update we do the same, but instead of doing it in the `enter` function of the join, we do it in the `update`.

Also, my SVG is structured in a different way, I have a stacks groups, then I have the stack group, and a bars group, in this bars group I add the rectangles. In the fiddle below, you can see that I added the parent group with the class `stack`.

The two functions are below:

updateStack:

```
  function updateStack(data) {
    // update the y scale
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map((d) => d.sum))]);
    g.select(".y").transition().duration(1000).call(yAxis);

    const stackData = stack(data);

    stackData.forEach((stackedBar) => {
      stackedBar.forEach((stack) => {
        stack.id = `${stackedBar.key}-${stack.data.year}`;
      });
    });

    let bars = g
      .selectAll("g.stacks")
      .selectAll(".stack")
      .data(stackData, (d) => {
        return d.key;
      });

    bars.join(
      (enter) => {
        const barsEnter = enter.append("g").attr("class", "stack");

        barsEnter
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "bars")
          .attr("fill", (d) => {
            return color(d.key);
          });

        updateRects(barsEnter.select(".bars"));

        return enter;
      },
      (update) => {
        const barsUpdate = update.select(".bars");
        updateRects(barsUpdate);
      },
      (exit) => {
        return exit.remove();
      }
    );
  }
```

updateRects:

```
  function updateRects(childRects) {
    childRects
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(
        (d) => d,
        (d) => d.id
      )
      .join(
        (enter) =>
          enter
            .append("rect")
            .attr("id", (d) => d.id)
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", (d) => x(d.data.year))
            .attr("y", y(0))
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .call((enter) =>
              enter
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("y", (d) => y(d[1]))
                .attr("height", (d) => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
            ),
        (update) =>
          update.call((update) =>
            update
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .attr("y", (d) => y(d[1]))
              .attr("height", (d) => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
          ),
        (exit) =>
          exit.call((exit) =>
            exit
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .attr("y", height)
              .attr("height", height)
          )
      );
  }
```

Here is an update jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5oqwLxdj/1/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Guillermo, thank you so much for your answer! You absolutely nailed it, perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

It is getting called, but you can't see it. Try changing `.attr(d => console.log('update stack'))` to `.attr(console.log('update stack'))`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, while that is true, it doesn't solve the 'How can I get this to work as expected?' part of the question. But thanks again for your effort!